# Python click module for creating a CLI

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using python click module to create a CLI. 
The fact is that I want to have category commands with arguments, for example:

```
myawesomecli env info
myawesomecli env clean
myawesomecli env ...

myawesomecli database create-table <name>
myawesomecli database insert <entry>
myawesomecli database ...
```

So far, I can come up with this:

```
import click
@click.group()
@click.version_option(version='0.1 ')
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument('option')
def env(option):
    if option == 'info':
        click.echo("run env info command")
    elif option == 'clean':
        click.echo("run env clean command")     
    ...

@cli.command()
@click.argument('option')
def database(option):
    if option == 'create-table':
        click.echo("run database create-table command")
    elif option == 'clean':
        click.echo("run database clean command")        
    ...
```

Is there a way to have a function for each subcommand instead of using the if-else's?

Comment: What library provides `click`?

Comment: `pip list|grep click  
click (6.6)`

Comment: You *could* provide a link.

Comment: Sure, I'm using this guide: http://click.pocoo.org/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import click
@click.group()
@click.version_option(version='0.1 ')
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group()
@click.argument('option')
def env(option):
   """ Define the environment of the product """
   pass

@env.command()
def info():
    click.echo("run env info command")

@env.command():
def group():
    click.echo("run env group command")
...
```

I'm also struggling to understand a few things but this is one idea that i hope helps.